# llenando lista con foreach c sharp y .net

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el q agrego items a una lista mediante un `foreach` este es mi código:

```
var archivosguardados = new List<Archivos>();
foreach (var a in modelArchivo)
                {
                    FactoryClass.ArchivoModelToArchivo(_bd, a, ref archivo);
                    archivosguardados.Add(archivo);

                }

                _bd.Archivos.AddRange(archivosguardados);
                _bd.SaveChanges();
```

Pasa que `archivosguardados` luego de recorrer el foreach tiene dos elementos pero estos son repetidos, y desde `modelArchivo` ya verifique que este pasando la lista correctamente.

Comment: Chequeaste cuantas veces se está ejecutando el foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el codigo veo que al invocar a `ArchivoModelToArchivo()` usas un parametro como `ref`, pero no veo donde defienes la variable `archivo`, recuerda que si usas valores por referencia estos apuntan a la misma direccion en memoria, por lo tanto pisaras los valores anteriores.

Intenta definiendo la variable de forma local al `foreach` a ver como resulta

```
foreach (var a in modelArchivo)
{
    Archivos archivo;
    FactoryClass.ArchivoModelToArchivo(_bd, a, ref archivo);

    archivosguardados.Add(archivo);
}
```

Otro consejo, cuando tienes metodo como estos no se usan parametros por referencia, sino que la funciona retorna el valor como respuesta

```
public Archivos ArchivoModelToArchivo(xxTipo _bd, xxTipo a)
{
    // aqui codigo

    return archivo;
}
```

entonces lo usarias

```
foreach (var a in modelArchivo)
{
    var archivo = FactoryClass.ArchivoModelToArchivo(_bd, a);

    archivosguardados.Add(archivo);
}
```

como veras queda mucho mejor

Comment: Oye muchas gracias, tenias razón, no sabes cuantas vueltas le di al asunto